# Edit Offset Values in Unity URP Lit Shader via Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-shaders, urp

I want to edit the Offset Parameter of Surface Input in Simple Lit Shader of URP in Unity, but I am not able to do so.

I tried using Method `SetTextureOffset` still cannot update the offset value.
Please Help

Here is the Offset I want to change via Script -

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it,

Instead of **"_MainTexture"** use **"_BaseMap"** in `SetTextureOffset` and it works